# Angular generate reactive form dynamically based on api call

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to dynamically generate select and input elements in an angular form based on an api call.

```
<div formArrayName="{{formControlValues.dropdownOption}}">
      <div *ngFor="let option of getDropdownOptions(addConcrete); let i=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field *ngFor="let drop of concrete.options.dropdownOptions">
            <mat-select placeholder="{{drop.display}}" formControlName="{{formControlValues.selection}}" id="{{formControlValues.selection}}" required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let select of drop.selections" [value]="select">
                {{select}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addConcrete.get(formControlValues.selection).hasError('required')">This is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The concrete.options.dropdownOptions is from an http GET call. So the form fails to build because it tries to build before getting the response body.  My corresponding typescript looks something like

```
createForm() {
    let controlsConfig = {};
    controlsConfig[this.formControlValues.dropdownOption] = this.fb.array(this.getAllDropOptions());
    this.addConcrete = this.fb.group(controlsConfig);
  }

  getAllDropOptions() {
    let array: Array<FormGroup> = new Array<FormGroup>();
    for(let dropOption of this.concrete.options.dropdownOptions) {
      array.push(this.getDropdownOption(dropOption.display));
    }
    return array;
  }

  getDropdownOption(display: string): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      display: [display],
      selection: ['']
    });
  }
```

Although this does not work, I am looking for a general solution on trying generate a form based on http returned data.

Comment: Put an *ngIf on your form tag that checks that data is retrieved before displaying form? Or initialize an empty form and then patch values when you have them.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I would appreciate an example of a reactive form being generated based on http response data

Comment: You could create a demo of your form on for example a stackblitz, you can emulate the data coming async with a timeout. I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: Thank you @Alex ! Your suggestion did in fact work, I just had to play around with the form controls and form arrays for a while to get the proper variables

Comment: Great, glad to hear you solved it :) :)